# Golang gRPC connection client side error - "error reading server preface: http2: frame too large"

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-run, http2

I'm writing a go client to consume

```
conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, serverAddr, grpc.WithBlock(), grpc.WithReturnConnectionError(), getTransportCredential(false))
```

The above call hangs until context timeout and returns the following error

```
failed to dial: context deadline exceeded: connection error: desc = "error reading server preface: http2: frame too large"
```

`getTransportCredential(insecure bool)` is defined below

```
func getTransportCredential(insecure bool) grpc.DialOption {
    if insecure {
        return grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure2.NewCredentials())
    }

    rootCAs, err := x509.SystemCertPool()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if rootCAs == nil {
        fmt.Println("SystemCertPool is nil")
        rootCAs = x509.NewCertPool()
    }

    caCert := `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

    if caCert != "" {
        // Append our cert to the system pool
        if ok := rootCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM([]byte(caCert)); !ok {
            fmt.Println("Couldn't add cert to the cert pool")
        }
    }

    creds := credentials.NewClientTLSFromCert(rootCAs, "")
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", creds.Info())
    return grpc.WithTransportCredentials(creds)
}
```

Could you please help me solve this problem?

I can `grpcurl` from my machine to the server and get a successful response.

Answer (score 2):

maximum frame size of http/2 is 2^14 (16384)[image]
you need to reduce yourself payload,

refer to: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#page-12, page 76

Comment: Thanks for the response. For some reason, I don't think the error was correctly representing the actual issue. I had to ```os.Unset(...)``` HTTP and HTTPS proxy env variables and bam, client was able to connect to the service.